# php globe array, separate first file of directory from

Tags: php, glob, scandir

I'm trying to get .php files in a directory to an array using globe(). Works fine.
Than I would like to have the first file in one div and all the others in another div.

```
    <?php
    $files = glob("kalenderitems/*.php");
    $num_files = count($files);
    $i = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?>-col-left">
    <?php
    foreach (glob("kalenderitems/*.php") as $filename){
    if ($i == 1) {
    ?>
    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?> nr-<?php echo $i++ ?> equaliser">
    <?php
    include $filename
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    };
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end DIV 1 -->
    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?>-col-right">
    <?php
    foreach (glob("kalenderitems/*.php") as $filename){
    if ($i++ > 1) {
     ?>
    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?> nr-<?php echo $i++ ?> equaliser">
    <?php
    include $filename
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    };
    }    
    ?>
    </div>
```

**Array content**
(glob("kalenderitems/*.php")) gives me:
insert1.php, insert2.php, insert3.php, insert4.php

**Goal Structure**

```
    <div class="col-left">
      <div class="element 1">include (insert1.php)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
      <div class="element 2">include a file</div>
      <div class="element 2">include a file</div>
      <div class="element 2">include a file</div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**
A php file must be included in the div's. Provided solution is only able to build the structure and put html in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php). It removes and returns the first element in an array, so this should achieve what you're aiming for:

```
<?php

$files      = glob("kalenderitems/*.php");
$num_files  = count($files);

?>
<div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files; ?>-col-left">
     <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files; ?> nr-1 equaliser">
        <?php include(array_shift($files)); ?>
     </div>
</div>

<!-- end DIV 1 -->
<div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?>-col-right">
    <?php foreach($files as $filename): ?>
        <?php include($filename); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Also big thanks for all your other guys making efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the inner div, i just wrote them.

```
    <?php
    $files = glob("kalenderitems/*.php");
    $num_files = count($files);
    $first_flag = 0;
    $div_1 = "";
    $div_2 = "";
    foreach (glob("kalenderitems/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        if ($first_flag == 0) 
        {

            $div_1 = "<div class='kal-item-$num_files nr-$i++ equaliser'> include $filename </div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $div_2.= "<div class='kal-item-$num_files nr-$i++ equaliser'> include $filename </div>";
        }
        $first_flag = 1;
    }

    ?>

    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?>-col-left">
        <?php echo $div_1; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="kal-item-<?php echo $num_files?>-col-right">
        <?php echo $div_2; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi, thx for the answer. This looks like it is going somewhere. But I have four items. The first one is now in col-left. Correct. But in Col-right I get only the last item. so 2 and 3 are missing.

Comment: changed the answer, plz chk now

Comment: And actually it does not. Gives the right structure, but also puts a line with the filename between the <div> and does not include the other file.

Comment: i am confused, do u want only file name to be displayed, or u want to include that file also.

Comment: No, the file is a little file where I let somebody edit text. So I want to realy include the file.

Comment: u mean u want show the data present in the file. Like " this file is for great work", right ?

Comment: Yes, I want the content of that include file displayed in the div's. each event.php file contains a div, h1, h2 and p. That I want between the kal-item divs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130021/discussion-between-user3799112-and-purushottam-zende).